# DuplicateTokenEx for changing windows sessions

Tags: c++, session, windows-7

I have a service which runs as system (in session 0) that is capable of spawning processes on the desktop (in user's sessions). I'm following the exact method described here: http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8389765/creating-a-process-in-another-user-session/

This code has been working for years, but I recently found out that the windows file I/O on the child programs is acting MUCH worse for the spawned process than if ran manually by a regular user.

The penalty can be seen by launching notepad (from the daemon running in session 0), and trying to open a file through the windows dialog. It takes more than 10 seconds just for the "open" file browser to come up. I used process monitor and saw that the File and registry access had almost 1,000,000 events. When doing the same process on a notepad launched manually, there are ~6,000 events.

I'm assuming I am missing some flag in the token impersonation, but I haven’t been able to find anything online. I ruled out my CreateProcessAsUser code by running it from session 1 vs session 0, and the session 1 code ran the same as the manual launch. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Extra information: This problem may be very specific because I have a roaming profile on the network instead of on the local machine.

Comment: Quote: "CreateProcessAsUser does not load the specified user's profile into the HKEY_USERS registry key. Therefore, to access the information in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key, you must load the user's profile information into HKEY_USERS with the LoadUserProfile function before calling CreateProcessAsUser. Be sure to call UnloadUserProfile after the new process exits."

Comment: Thanks for the response! I double-checked and I am calling the LoadUserProfile function when I step down from System to user. Sorry I overlooked that in my original post.